# I want a batch file to delete old files from a specific subfolder in all of the folders in a directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory `D:\AX` with several subdirectories.  Each of these subdirectories has a child directory named `destination`.

I want to delete all `.pdf` files older than 90 days inside of each of these `destination` directories.

My first try was:

```bash
forfiles /p "D:\AX\*\destination" /s /m *.PDF /D -90 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

But I figured out you can have a wildcard in the middle of the filepath.

My latest try is:

```bash
for /D %%G IN ( "D:\AX") do (forfiles /p "%%G\destination" /s /m *.PDF /D -90 /C "cmd /c del @path")
```

Not working, but I am not familiar enough to know what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I was missing the wildcard in my filepath.

It needed to be:

```bash
for /D %%G IN ( "D:\AX\*") do…
```